# Regarding C Pointer scope

Tags: c, pointers, scope, bounds

I have some generic questions.

1. Are there pointers whose scope encompasses the whole program?
2. Are there programs that have out of bounds pointers which are used to access and manipulate out of bounds stuff? Any example?
3. Can bounds checking be applied on all pointer scopes without incurring false positives or program stalls? What are the disadvantages of bounds checking? Are there some programs where they cannot be applied?

Comment: Regarding 2, what do you mean exactly with "out of bound"-stuff? And i think our defition of "scope" of a variable is also different...

Comment: Always think of C as the most basic you can; the scope is the scope, there is not special cases: where you declare something is where you can access it; if you declare a pointer at the most top (the global scope) you can access it anywere.

Comment: A pointer is like any other variable; it is free to have external linkage and thus be visible to the whole program (note that this is a linker thing). Any out-of-bounds access and manipulation invokes undefined behavior, so I don't think there is a valid example to show. Bounds checking can be applied wherever you want, as long as you implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do i calculate the upper bounds for a data dependent jump/pointer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Pointers don't differ from other types of variables with regards to their scope: Global variables are in scope from where they are declared until the end of the compilation unit (except when they are shadowed by a local variable of the same name).

   So if you store a pointer in a global variable that has a unique name and is declared at the beginning of the compilation unit, it will be in scope for the entire compilation unit.
2. Yes, buggy programs. An example of such a program would be this:

   ```
   int main(void) {
       int arr[] = {1,2,3};
       arr[23] = 42;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Yes, a given compiler+libc combo could perform bound checks on all uses of pointers at run time and such checks would not incur false positives. The disadvantage would be the performance cost of keeping track of the necessary metadata and actually applying the checks. They could be applied to every program, but if a program has strict performance requirement, those may no longer be met with the checks.

Comment: I would upvote this if it were more accurate on 1). Global variables are not necessarily in scope in the whole program. You can have a global variable with internal linkage (through the use of `static`); only global variables with external linkage are visible to every translation unit in a program.

Comment: Strictly speaking, C has no "global" variables. Variables with file scope (defined outside any function) are in scope from the point of declaration to the end of the translation unit (source file). Scope and linkage are two different things.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I was thinking "compilation unit" when I said "program". I'll correct that.

Comment: How do you calculate the upper bounds of.say. a data dependent branch?

Comment: So there is no way for an attacker to circumvent a program that has bounds checking for every pointer/variable?

Comment: What if the bounds is big enough that an overflow occurs inside it? is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, for 2). I meant Legal programs :)